# XtraTabbedMdiManager Layout (Tile Vertical, Tile Horizontal. Tile Cascade)

Tags: c#, devexpress, mdichild, windows-ribbon-framework

I have ribbon form with 3 button..
I want to change the tabbed child form become Vertical, Horizontal, or Cascade...
is there how to do it ?

If using frmmain with property

> ismdiContainer=true

```
private void btn1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     form1 frm1 = new form1();
     frm1.MdiParent=this;
     frm1.Show();
}

private void btnVertical_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
}

private void btnHorizontal_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
}

private void btnCascade_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
}
```

the Question is, How to change the Layout when I press the btnVertical to Change the Layout

Comment: What the exactly wrong with the code above? What are the results you are expecting? Because it is not quite clear how the layouts of MDI-forms related to the layout of XtraTabbedMdiManager's tabs.

Comment: when the Btn1 is clicked the form is show in tabbed...
what I want is how to make the showing child form become tile Vertical, Horizontal or Cascade ? with out removing the XtraTabbedMdiManager @DmitryG

Comment: The XtraTabbedMdiManager is designed for displaying MDI-children as tabs. If you don't want to use tabs you should either remove the XtraTabbedMdiManager or nullify the XtraTabbedMdiManager.MdiParent property. Take a look my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `LayoutMdi` method work, just remove the XtraTabbedMdiManager from your form or nullify the [XtraTabbedMdiManager.MdiParent](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTabbedMdi.XtraTabbedMdiManager.MdiParent.property) property because the MdiLayout mode is not applicable for XtraTabbedMdiManager's tabs:

```
void btnVertical_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     xtraTabbedMdiManager1.MdiParent = null; // turn off tabs
     LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
}
```

As an alternative solution, you can try the [DocumentManager](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/11359/Controls-and-Libraries/Application-UI-Manager) component with it's [Native MDI View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/11356/Controls-and-Libraries/Application-UI-Manager/Views/Native-MDI-View).

Comment: thanks it works now, I just need to find how to put it become tabbed when the form is dragged...

thank you @DmitryG